# How do I convince Bison to parse part of a file?

Tags: bison, yacc

If a have a input file of the form:

```
BEGIN
  stuff....
END

BEGIN
  stuff ...
END
```

and my .y file is of the form

```
%token BEGIN
%token END
%start begin

begin:  BEGIN stuff END
```

and what I want to do is call yyparse repeatedly, parsing a single BEGIN/END, until eof.

The first call to yyparse reports:

```
syntax error, unexpected BEGIN, expecting $end.
```

which makes sense; bison wants to parse the entire file. Is there a way to have bison be
more flexible in it's defintion of $end?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to add a (pair of) productions to the top of the .y file:

```
input: begin | input begin;
```

Now yyparse will parse multiple inputs.  If your REALLY want to have to call yyparse multiple times, you could instead probably get away with:

```
begin: BEGIN stuff END { YYACCEPT; } ;
```

`YYACCEPT` is a special builtin that causes yyparse to return immediately with 0 (after doing any needed internal cleanup).  I say "probably" as this will only work if bison reduces `begin` with a default reduction (no lookahead).  That will be the case if this is the only rule for `begin` and `begin` is not used in a context where recognizing it requires lookahead.

Comment: I would prefer to call yyparse repeatedly; it makes more sense for this particular application.

Comment: I would prefer to call yyparse repeatedly; it makes more sense for this particular application. YYACCEPT returns *immediately*, not performing the semantic rule; I added "begin0: begin {YYACCEPT;} ;" to make it work. It now processes all of the blocks, and errors at the EOF. I need to add an empty rule to handle EOF, and I think that will make it work. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, adding a empty rule that sets the tree root pointer to null to signal the calling app that eof was reached seems to work.

Comment: `YYACCEPT` is *in* the semantic action -- if you already had an action on `begin` you could add `YYACCEPT` to (the end of) that action

Comment: >> YYACCEPT is in the semantic action.  Ooops. Yes. I had formatted it as a midrule and confused myself. All better now. Thanks.

Comment: The empty rule is not actually working; it's returning on EOF or on gibberish. What I suppose I need is an EOF rule, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Okay, looked at bison-end-of-file, and it passes all of my regression tests now.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your grammar:

```
all_begins: begins
          ;

begins: begins begin
      | begin
      ;
```

Replace the %start with:

```
%start all_begins
```

And just call yyparse() once.