# recover yyparse after yyaccept

Tags: c, bison

Friends, I am parsing a bibtex file, having multiple bibtex entry within a file, e.g.

```
@Book{a1,
    Title="ASR",
    Publisher="oxf",
    Author = {a {\"m}ook, Rudra Banerjee},
    Year="2010",
    Address="UK",
    Edition="1",
}
@Article{a2,
    Author="Rudra Banerjee",
    Title="Fe{\"Ni}Mo",
    Publisher="P{\"R}B",
    Number="12",
    Pages="36690",
    Year="2011",
    Address="UK",
    Edition="1",
}
```

Now, I want yyparse to return after each entry, hence, my parser is:

```
%union
{
    char    *sval;
};
%token <sval> VALUE
%token <sval> KEY
%token OBRACE
%token EBRACE
%token QUOTE
%token SEMICOLON 

%start Input
%%
Input: 
     /* empty */ 
     | Input Entry ;  /* input is zero or more entires */
Entry: 
     '@' KEY '{' KEY ','{ 
              g_hash_table_insert(table, g_strdup("TYPE"), g_strdup($2));
                  g_hash_table_insert(table, g_strdup("ID"), g_strdup($4));
          g_printf("%s:%s\n","KEY=>",g_hash_table_lookup(table,"TYPE"));
//                  g_printf("%s: %s\n", $2, $4);
              } 
     KeyVals '}'
     {YYACCEPT;}
     ;
KeyVals: 
       /* empty */ 
       | KeyVals KeyVal ; /* zero or more keyvals */
KeyVal: 
      KEY '=' VALUE ',' { g_hash_table_insert(table, g_strdup($1), g_strdup($3));
//                          g_printf("%s: %s\n", $1, $3);
                           g_printf("%s:%s\n",$1,g_hash_table_lookup(table,$1));
              };

%%
```

and in main routine, it is called as:

```
do{
   yyparse();
  }
```

The problem is, it is parsed correctly, but only the first entry; i.e. it is not recovering from the YYACCEPT.
How I can make the code recall the yyparse again after yyaccept?

This is almost same question as [How do I convince Bison to parse part of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564563/how-do-i-convince-bison-to-parse-part-of-a-file) But I have failed to solve my problem.

Comment: The above looks correct (modulo C syntax), and should work as `Entry` has a default reduction.  In what way is it not working?  You'll need to reset your global `table` before calling `yyparse()` again, of course.  Try compiling with `-DYYDEBUG` and setting `yydebug=1` before calling yyparse for more info about what the parser is doing.

Comment: @ChrisDodd, Thanks for your reply.
If I print the output,
`$ ./parse <u2.bib 
KEY=>:Book
Title:"ASR"
Publisher:"oxf"
Author:{a {\"m}ook, Rudra Banerjee}
Year:"2010"
Address:"UK"
Edition:"1"
    `
is all what I am getting, i.e. it is parsing the first entry correctly, but not returnning to the next entry.
Kindly help

Answer (score 1):

You should enable the `%debug` traces to check what is going on.  Also, given what you are trying to do, you should probably give a try to push parsers instead (http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Push-Decl.html).